# Python reading where data in columns and need to print in tabular form

Tags: python

I am new to python and recently have started.

In Python if I m reading through a file, where all data is in columns:

```
Name
State
City
Name
State
City
...
snippet
```

I want to read each and every line and print and store output to new file, how to do that in python

I need output like

```
Name   State City
Cities State City
.......
snippet
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  While we like to help, we also encourage users to do their own research BEFORE posting.  There are plenty of tutorials online for how to read from and write to files in Python.  Have you read any of these?  Can you also clarify the input file format and output file format?

Comment: Please show what you have done so far, i.e. some effort and code samples. The community can help you then, but as it stands, your question is too broad and unlikely to result in the answers you hope to receive. Nevertheless, welcome to StackOverflow!